# Why can I not read getId?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, typeerror

When using the `getSheets(file)` method, I receive the following **error**:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getId')`

This is the code:

```
function getSheets(file) {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId()).getSheetByName("sheet2");
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId())
  var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("URLxxx").getSheetByName("sheet1");

 var allsheets = sourceSheet.getSheets();

  for(var i in allsheets){
    if(allsheets[i].getName().includes("X")){
      Logger.log(allsheets[i].getName());
      copyData(allsheets[i],destSheet);

  }
}

function copyData(sourceSheet,destSheet){
    var nextRow = destSheet.getLastRow() + 1;

    var numRows = sourceSheet.getLastRow() ;
    
    var source = sourceSheet.getRange(16,3,numRows,54);


    destSheet.getRange(nextRow,1,numRows,54).setValues(source.getValues());


}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show more of your code, specifically where you are calling this function. Also, you're overwriting the same variable `sourceSheet`? (Unrelated)

Comment: If you are calling this function then you must provide it with a file name.  If you don't wish to do that you can modify the function declaration to something like this function getSheets(file="filename"); this provides the only parameter with a default value.  If you wish to learn more about function you can read any of the online resources for JavaScript.

Comment: The question doesn't include enough details. You should describe how the function is called.  If you are running it by clicking the run button on the Google Apps Script editor, that is the reason for the problem, as the run button doesn't assign a value / object to the function parameters. P.S. There have been a lot of questions like this that have been asked before

Answer (score -1):

`file` is undefined, hence it does not have a `getId()` method. You could add a safety check to `getSheets` to avoid these assumptions, like

```
function getSheets(file) {
  if (file != undefined) {
    var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId()).getSheetByName("sheet2");
    var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId())
    var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("URLxxx").getSheetByName("sheet1");
  } else {
    //the file was undefined, you may handle that here
  }
}
```

You could also make sure that you do not call `getSheets` when you have no file to get the sheet from.

Comment: the sourceSheet is sheet2? how would I define this please?

Comment: @SarahH does `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2')` help? (possibly in lower-case)

Comment: that does make the code run without errors but then it doesn't get the data ?

Comment: @SarahH how did you test this exactly?